# Chrome browser launches with blank page in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing issues while executing one of my Selenium test script on chrome browser. When selenium launches chrome browser then it opened with no URL on it i.e. Blank page. 
 Also getting the pop up that chromedriver.exe has stopped working.

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please tell me the version of the Chrome and chromedriver

Comment: Chromedriver version : 2.22 and chrome version is 2.57

Comment: Chrome version should like 55,56,57... there is not 2.57, since your chromedriver version is 2.22, please try Chrome 52

Comment: Mybad... it is 57

Comment: please try chromedriver 2.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try chromedriver 2.29, it should work fine https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.29/