# How to use two classes in same package where one class is dependent on other class?

Tags: selenium, automation

My class 1 is 'Login'
My class 2 is 'checkout'

To run a class 2(checkout), I have to first log in(class 1) so my class 2 is dependent on class 1. But when I run the below code, a blank chrome screen is shown:
[Chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl7zV.jpg)

The chrome driver is not going to the URL I have provided it just stuck with the blank screen.
My class 1 is a login class and to do a checkout, I need to first login so when I am doing that its not working.

Please let me know whats the mistake I am doing here?

**Class 1 code:**

```
package testcases;

public class Login{

static WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();    
        @BeforeClass
        public void init() {

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("URL");
        }            
        @Test

        public static void testcase1()  
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("testid@g.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("3222");       driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();       
        }
```

**Class 2 code:**

```
public class checkout {
static WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

@BeforeClass    
public void init() {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("URL");
    } 

@Test(dependsOnMethods={"com.test.Login.testcase1"})
    public void checkout() throws InterruptedException{

            System.out.println("test");
            driver.quit(); }}
```

**testng.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none" preserve-order="true">
<test name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="com.test.Login"/>
  <class name="com.test.checkout"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Errors:**
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEw8u.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us the *entire* stack trace, and not just a screen shot of the lower parts of it?

Comment: org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.findDependedUponMethods(MethodHelper.java:114)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.topologicalSort(MethodHelper.java:241)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.sortMethods(MethodHelper.java:317)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.collectAndOrderMethods(MethodHelper.java:6
)

Answer (score 0):

Could please update Chrome Driver and Chrome Browser to latest and retry and confirm
[Chrome browser launches with blank page in Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511081/chrome-browser-launches-with-blank-page-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I have updated both my chrome version: 68.0 - chromedriver: 2.29
But still not working. Also, I tried with this version: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.41/ but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are following Page Object model or not.

You need to make changes accordingly :

1. There is no need to create **instance of WebDriver** in **check out class**. You can just pass the **reference** of **driver** from **Login Class**.
2. You need to **set the path of chromeDriver** before launching it.
3. You can introduce **Groups** and **dependsOnGroups** concept. Make `testcase1()`  in a **group** which is present in **Login class** and make  `checkout()` method as depends on groups by introducing `dependsOnGroups` concept.

Here you can follow this code :

**Login.java**

```
public class Login  {

static WebDriver driver; 

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();  
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }  


    @Test(groups={"Login.testcase1"})
    public static void testcase1()  
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("testid@g.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("3222");  
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click(); 
        getCheckoutPage(driver);
    }

    public static  CheckOut getCheckoutPage(WebDriver driver) {
        return new CheckOut(driver);
    }
}
```

Checkout.java

```
public class CheckOut {

     private WebDriver driver;

    public CheckOut(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver; 
    }

    @Test(dependsOnGroups={"Login.testcase1"})
    public void checkout() throws InterruptedException{
                System.out.println("test");
                driver.quit(); }

}
```

Comment: I have used your code but errors were shown:
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
  Options:
    -configfailurepolicy
      Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
    -d
      Output directory
    -dataproviderthreadcount
      Number of threads to use when running data providers
    -excludegroups
      Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
    -groups
      Comma-separated list of group names to be run
    -junit

Comment: Also, I cannot use this:     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
because I am using Mac. In Mac, we have to add the driver file in the bin folder.

Comment: I have made updates with your code and did run as "TestNG"

Comment: @Rozmeen : Ok, I wasn't aware of your system.

Comment: Well , you can return the object of checkout class from `testcase1`. Like I did

Comment: I have used the exact same code as you have provided.

Comment: Dependent on groups is a good choice for this kind of scenario. and the error you are getting those are related to testng not JAVA

Comment: Yeah do I have to change anything to the XML file?

Comment: If you are using `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none" preserve-order="true">
<test name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="com.test.Login"/>
  <class name="com.test.checkout"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->` , then no need to change anything.

Comment: you can remove `<class name="com.test.checkout"/>` and run the script

Comment: When am I running the login.java then its working fine but when I am running Checkout class then these errors are shown.

Comment: When you are running login.java, did the method present under checkout got executed ?

Comment: I got this in console after running login.java:

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db) on port 5243
Only local connections are allowed.
Jul 31, 2018 2:13:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
PASSED: testcase1

Comment: No, that's not an error , but after execution of testcase1 which is in login.java , did anything happen ?

Comment: No nothing happened.

Comment: then set the binary path for checkout also  and then check.

Comment: Not sure how to set that?

Comment: I mean in mac you have to set some path , right ? (I don't have any idea about mac and path bin path se up)

Comment: No in mac, we don't do that, we just have to put the driver file in the bin folder.